# Automatically trim trailing spaces from query join clause with AsTracking - EF Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two classes (Item and Location)

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Rack { get; set; }
    public string IdItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

I have a foreign key between these tables with Item.Id and Location.ItemId.
On Item table, the Id column have spaces after the Id (example : '123    ').
But on the Location table, on the Item column, I have no space after the Id (example: '123').

When I make queries with AsNoTracking() the trimmed join works as expected (thanks to SQL-92 ANSI/ISO), however it doesn't work with AsTracking() and the relation becomes empty. The two generated queries are identical, EF Core doesn't seem to be able to deserialize the SQL data from relations in a tracking scenario.

```cs
//Locations are returned (Locations.Count > 0)
var Locations = db.Item.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(i => i.Locations)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == "123")?.Locations;

//Locations are not returned (Count = 0)
var Locations = db.Item
    .Include(i => i.Locations)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == "123")?.Locations;
```

Is it a bug in EF Core? Is there any workaround?

Comment: How can you compare an integer field (`Id`) with a string ("123") ?

Comment: I made a mistake in the example, the Id is indeed string

Comment: `When I make queries with AsNoTracking() the trimmed join works as expected (thanks to SQL-92 ANSI/ISO), however it doesn't work with AsTracking() and the relation becomes empty` <- This has to do with the returned value and tracking changes in memory. EF sees "123 " as a different key value than "123" so the entity is not the same when building up the object graph. I suggest you do not use leading or trailing spaces in your key values unless they have an actual meaning and you want them to be differentiated by those spaces.

Comment: At any rate, it's a bug in EF. I tested it and the items *and* locations are loaded (check the `Local` collections of the `DbSet`s), but not connected by relationship fixup. EF should use database semantics in relationship fixup. Please post an issue in EF's github.

Comment: Why would you want to use approximately consistent key/foreign key? I would make the two keys identical so you can enforce referential integrity in the database, as well as in EF.

Comment: I assume that in both cases generated SQL is the same?

Comment: I have no choice to leave trailing spaces in the database column. There might be bugs if I remove them. I found an article by Rowan Miller explaining how to create an interceptor to trim trailing Blanks in String Joins. But this article is for EF 6.1 and not for EF Core.
https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/

Comment: Check this [interceptor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-preview7-entity-framework/#simple-actions-on-entity-creation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a bug, so please go and report it to EF Core GitHub issue tracker.

Meanwhile, you can use the following workaround which utilizes a custom [ValueComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5) inside your `OnModelCreating` override:

```cs
var trimmingStringEndValueComparer = new ValueComparer<string>(
    (v1, v2) => v1 == null ? v2 == null : v2 != null && v1.TrimEnd() == v2.TrimEnd(),
    v => v.TrimEnd().GetHashCode());

modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().Property(e => e.Id)
    .Metadata.SetValueComparer(trimmingStringEndValueComparer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. I will post an issue on EF Core Github.